# How do I use the default click sound using view.playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I wan to use the default `TICK` sound but I dont know how or where to put this code

```
view.playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);
```

I found this code in another post.

This is the code I have:

```
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.blah);

        Button Button01 = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        Button01.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                mp.start();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onClick(View v){}

    public void disclaimerBTN (View v){
        Toast.makeText(this, "FAILED:      The remote object is " +
                            "not responding to this command",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

So where would I put the `view.play`..... code?
Much appreciated.

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Nothing. I'm a total newb and dont have any idea where to put it. The code you see is all the code I have ever done. I'm trying to self teach and its slow going.

Comment: @RictaScott : put this `playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);`   inside button click

Comment: "button click" being similar to                  Button Button01 = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        Button01.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                mp.start();
            }                                                                                 in the above code. yes?

Comment: use replace mp.start(); with playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For Using [AudioManager.playSoundEffect](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#playSoundEffect%28int,%20float%29) on Button click event you can try as:

```
AudioManager audioManager = 
            (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

 Button01.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                 audioManager.playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);   
                 //mp.start();
            }
        });
```

for reference you can see this example on Google source code:

http://code.google.com/p/android-traditional-chinese-ime/source/browse/trunk/src/com/googlecode/tcime/SoundMotionEffect.java?r=13

Comment: Should actually be `audioManager.playSoundEffect(` **`AudioManager.FX_KEY_CLICK`** `);` instead of `audioManager.playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);` as per the doc, but both constants happen to be zero, so the effect is the same.

Answer (score 3):

You can play a sound from every view just by calling it this way:

```
Button01.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                 v.playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);   
            }
        });
```

Just note that the sound will not play if touch sounds are off by default. This is set in the general device sound preferences (Settings-->Sound-->Audible or on newer OS: Options > Sound > Touch)

Also, if this setting is set, most click events will trigger the click sound anyway!