# Android click sound

Tags: android

does anybody know how add click sound for button in Android? here is my code below..
i have checked some tutorials, but im not sure how to implement them on my code..

and why am i getting error when i put the folder name which contain the mp3 file?

http://s822.photobucket.com/user/backalleylive/media/android_test_error.jpg.html

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    MediaPlayer clicksound;

    public void onClick(View a){
        switch (a.getId()){
        case R.id.login:
            Intent b = new Intent (this, play.class);
            startActivity(b);
            break;
        case R.id.admin:
            Intent c = new Intent (this, admin.class);
            startActivity(c);
            break;
        case R.id.exit:
            finish();
            break;

        }

    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        View playButton = findViewById(R.id.login);
        playButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        View adminButton = findViewById(R.id.admin);
        adminButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        View exitButton = findViewById(R.id.exit);
        exitButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Usually, this isn't necessary. By adding a click listener to a view, the default click will play, just as long as the user hasn't disabled them. If the user has disabled click sounds, don't be a jerk by playing them anyway.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use the default click sound using view.playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13680163/how-do-i-use-the-default-click-sound-using-view-playsoundeffectsoundeffectconst)

Answer (score -1):

For simple click sound effect to work you need to have Touch Sound enabled in Android settings. Though your app can do that for you, but then you'll need to require specific permission for it.

Namely this one (inside `AndroidManifest.xml`'s manifest tags):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
```

Now once your app starts enable the touch sound like this:

```
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SOUND_EFFECTS_ENABLED, 1);
```

Unfortunately the sound is on all the views now, so you'll have to disable them on those which shouldn't have one. That can be done by adding additional tag to all views:

```
android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
```

Even more unfortunate that the sounds now are enabled on all of the device so you'll want to disable them as soon as user leaves your application with this:

```
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SOUND_EFFECTS_ENABLED, 0);
```

That's a lot of trouble for something as little as a click sound :-)
Even more so you would need to make sure that the sound is not heard when user pressed device buttons like back or home.

Another way out would be to do

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SOUND_EFFECTS_ENABLED, 1);
        v.playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);
        Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SOUND_EFFECTS_ENABLED, 0);
    }
});
```

Not sure how that constant setting switching affects performance though.

Also remember that the user could already have the setting turned on so you would first need to check

```
Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(),Settings.System.SOUND_EFFECTS_ENABLED,0);
```

EDIT:

Here's a better way to play sounds on click rather than switching settings around.

Have your sound file inside of the raw folder, and you can play it like this:

```
final MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound);
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mPlayer.start();
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you _really_ think modifying the system settings is a good idea?

Comment: I'll leave that for the OP to decide. It's a valid answer unlike others, which.. oh wait there aren't any.

Comment: You've correctly answered the question with `v.playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);`. Unfortunately you've wrapped it up with a recommendation to write to the system settings, which is very bad advice.

Comment: With that only it wouldn't be a correct answer imo. Because if the user has the touch sound disabled there will be no sound, with this method or without.

Comment: If touch sound is disabled, touch sounds shouldn't play.

Comment: i have tried but why am i getting this error when i put the name of the folder which contain the mp3 file?http://s822.photobucket.com/user/backalleylive/media/android_test_error.jpg.html

Comment: OP, check my edit. @Krylez It's your opinion, though if everyone did as they *should or shouldn't* we wouldn't have uniqueness in this world :-)

Comment: I mean how to integrate this mediaplayer above with android manager so as to have the volume controlled by systemservice